# C# Windows 8 App and converting textbox to int

Tags: c#, windows-8

I'm trying to make a BMI Calculator and I'm getting an invalidcastexception on this line of code.

```
int heightInchToFoot = (12 * Convert.ToInt32(heightFtBox)) + Convert.ToInt32(heightInchBox);
```

I've set the input scope to number for both heightFtBox and heightInchBox, which are both textblocks so I don't know why this exception happens. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use the Text property of the TextBlock to get the contents.
Try:

```
int heightInchToFoot = (12 * Convert.ToInt32(heightFtBox.Text)) + Convert.ToInt32(heightInchBox.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Forget that the `Convert` class exists.  Its methods accept `object` parameters, which effectively defeats type checking.

If you did your parsing of numeric values with `int.Parse` (or `int.TryParse` for local error handling), the compiler would catch you when you try to pass a UI widget instead of a string.  As Mark Peters points out, the string you want is the `Text` property of the widget.

The *numerictype*`.Parse` functions also accept an optional parameter controlling the locale settings for the conversion.